# How to search and replace with sub in Python

Tags: python, latex

I want to change all my references in latex from `\cite{authoryear}` to `[\Citealt{authoryear}]`.

To do so I tried

```
re.sub(r"\cite{[a-zA-Z0-9]}", r"[\Citealt{a-zA-Z0-9]}]", "bla bla \cite{doe2013}")
```

but this isn't working at all. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I tried `re.sub(r'\cite{(.*)}', r'[\Citealt{\1}]', '\cite{123}')` but it still gives \\[\\Cite{123}]. What to do with this backslashes?

Comment: That was because it should be `r'\\cite...`.  with a double `\\`.

Comment: If you're open to alternatives to `sub`, here is a similar question and solution using TexSoup, http://https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup:  "Latex command substitution using regexp in python" https://stackoverflow.com/a/50149523/4855984

Answer (score 1):

You can use backreferences. You should look at re.sub documentation http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub I created a small example:

```
re.sub(r'\cite{(.*)}', r'[\Citealt{\1}]', '\cite{123}')
```

Parentheses denote groups, they are numbered by the order in which opening parenthesis appears. You can refer to first nine groups by using backreferences \1 ... \9.

Comment: Actually this answers has several issues: it does not work when multiple `\cite{}` are present and it does not handle correctly the '\`.

Answer (score 0):

Question has been asked long ago and the author probably doesn't care about it anymore... but this is AFAIK a better answer to the problem:

```
re.sub(r'\\cite{(.*?)}', r'[\\Citealt{\1}]', '\\cite{123} -- \\cite{234}')
```

In particular, this takes into consideration several elements:

- Multiple references in a single string => `.*?` with lazy quantifier
- Proper handling of escape character `\`